# Como fazer preg_mach_all em linhas diferentes?

Tags: php

```
<div class="information di-ib mt4">
    Movie (1 eps)<br>
    Aug 2016 - Aug 2016<br>
    380,496 members
</div></div>
```

Quero fazer `preg_match_all` neste código, mas não sei como fazer em concreto o número de episódios.

Comment: Primeiramente, faça o [tour] para aprender a utilizar corretamente o site. Segundamente, você quer apenas obter o número de episódios, no caso, o valor 1?

Comment: sim é isso que quero

Comment: E esse valor sempre será seguido da palavra `eps`?

Comment: sim sera sempre seguido por eps

Answer (score 2):

Se o texto possuir apenas dados de um filme, você pode utilizar a função `preg_match`:

```
if (preg_match("/\((?P<qtd>\d+) eps\)/", $data, $matches))
{
  echo "O filme possui ", $matches["qtd"], " episódio(s)", PHP_EOL;
}
```

A saída para o texto em questão seria:

```
O filme possui 1 episódio(s)
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/02ULsh).

Porém, se o texto possuir informações de mais de um filme de fato será necessário o uso da função `preg_match_all`:

```
if (preg_match_all("/\((?P<qtd>\d+) eps\)/", $data, $matches))
{
  print_r($matches["qtd"]);
}
```

A única diferença é que `$matches["qtd"]` será uma lista de valores referentes a todos os filmes.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/mLpTQ8).

A expressão regular utilizada em ambos os casos é:

```
/\((?P<qtd>\d+) eps\)/
```

O objetivo dela é encontrar todos os grupos no formato `(X eps)`, sendo `X` um valor inteiro.

1. A parte `\(` escapa o caractere `(` e indica o início do grupo desejado;
2. A parte `(?P<qtd>\d+)` captura qualquer sequência de números, gerando o grupo nomeado `qtd`;
3. A parte `eps` faz ser necessário que a sequência de números seja seguida por esse texto;
4. A parte `\)` escapa o caractere `)` e indica o final do grupo desejado;

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Se possível, marque a resposta como aceita pressionando o botão **✓** ao lado esquerdo da resposta. Ainda, se julgou a resposta boa, pode votar positivamente nela pressionando o ícone **^**, também ao lado esquerdo da resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Usando `preg_match_all`:

```
<?php
$dado = "
<div class='information di-ib mt4'>
    Movie (1 eps)<br>
    Aug 2016 - Aug 2016<br>
    380,496 members
</div>";
preg_match_all("/(?<=\()[\d]/",$dado,$saida,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($saida[0]);//Array ( [0] => 1 )
?>
```

[Teste Ideone](http://ideone.com/YW2phb)

[Explicação da regex (inglês)](https://regex101.com/r/PXPq3a/1)